# keeping track of changes for doctors, clients and appointments :)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is not a normal use case where i could use sth like paper_trail or other plugins, it's a more complex approach to keep track changes... but let me explain:

Let's assume you have an medical calendar with appointments, an doctor in charge and client.

Let's assume you are Bill, and you are in charge of planning the schedule for the next couple of weeks. After settung up all those hundreds of appointments for the next month you send out the schedule to your doctors and clients.

Obviously if you plan 4 weeks ahead, there will be changes in your original schedule (you switch a doctor because one got sick, a client died, you change the start time of an appointment etc.)

So, you need to send an updated of the schedule. But obviously you want to send an email only to those clients or doctors how are affected from those changes in the schedule.

**What you need to figure out is:**

- new appointments ?
- changed appointments?
- canceled appointments?

Looks fairly simple at first, you could just remember the timestamp where you send the schedule the last time and then keep track changes with after_save, after_destroy callbacks.

Unfortunatly this will also result in some tricky cases, e.g. you remove a doctor, and add the same doctor again to that appointment. you get 2 changes which are obviously no "real" changes.

What i like to have is seperate table where i store those changes, reviews them later on and send those out to the doctors and clients.

I'm really curious if someone did a similar thing, or has an nice approach how to solve this problem. :)

Thanks !

Comment: Note that doctors and staff besides those involved in a scheduled event need to know the schedules of other doctors, for a variety of reasons. Also, the "no change" events, if they occur over time, *are* changes: if I'm told I don't have an appointment, I may reschedule something; if it changes again, even when it changes soon, that can have an impact.

Comment: yes, definitely. i can solve this with deleting (or mark as 'send') recorded changes if i submit the new schedule. so, if i remove the doctor send the update (=> clean ‘changes‘ history) and add the doctor again it will be 2 changes. if i do that in one cycle (remove and add) it is not worth sending. again, awesome test case !

Comment: If this is a real problem, don't write it hypothetically asking us to assume things. Scheduling systems are complicated and have a lot of edge/corner cases; As a result there is no simple answer or nice approach.

Comment: right. but i got some good input already, and there is always somebody how hase done sth. you might want do develop. i prefer to ask. maybe i can even share my solution ? who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for observing state changes is rather simple: use a log file. In your case it's going be a log file on steroids, a model, with attributes like: `user_to_update`, `date_changed`, `notified_ok`.

You can trigger a new log insert every time you make changes and retrieve statistics from your log model.

Comment: yeah, i guess that's the solution i have to go with. i think i have to add method like valid_change? and cleanup_log to remove/clean changes if a new change comes in which makes an old one invalid... i can see some nice test cases here :)

Comment: You are absolutely right about cleanup_log . One interesting statistic is how many changes are made on one appointment ( it could point some management bottlenecks ) . Anyway , logs are one of the solutions in your case .

Comment: nice, haven't thought about that. i can even find out which doctor/client is the most reliable. i gonna keep that in mind for a later release!

Answer (score 1):

You can try PaperTrail gem to track changes https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail